# How do I reference a ViewFlipper in my Activity from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have a dialogfragment and when the user clicks "Ok" on the dialog it is dismissed and I want to re-draw the activity layout.  I am using a viewflipper for the three layouts that are set up in the Activity.  Do I use getActivity() within the fragment to access the viewflipper?

partial Activity file:

```
...
private ViewFlipper viewflipper;

protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cardviewinput);
    viewflipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
```

partial xml file:

```
...
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"  >

    <ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewFlipper1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/cardview_nobuttons"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewNobuttons"  />

    <include layout="@layout/cardview_previewbuttons"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewPreviewbuttons" />

    <include layout="@layout/cardview_twobuttons"
        android:id="@+id/cardviewTwobuttons"  />

    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

partial fragment file:

```
...
@Override
   public void onClick(View v) { 
   ...   
   dismiss();
   getActivity().viewflipper.setDisplayedChild(viewflipper.indexOfChild
       (findViewById(R.id.cardviewNobuttons)));
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a getter for the viewflipper in the activity,then cast getActivity to your activity type and access the viewflipper.

Comment: In the activity : public ViewFlipper getFlipper(){return viewflipper;} in fragment (youractivity)getActivity.getViewFlipper